# Hibernation randomly fails with black screen

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, power-management, suspend, hibernate

Hibernation *sometimes* works, but many times:

- **Screen flashes** *then* goes blank, black, or just returns to desktop view.
- **Everything freezes entirely**, not even typing in the blind works.
- **Nothing happens** *after* 1-2 seconds of disk I/O.

System setup:

- Nvidia Optimus using `bumblebee` and proprietary drivers.
- ArchLinux with everything at the latest
- Unencrypted drives
- `bumblebee` fails after wake from suspend, which I don't know if related.

There are not errors or anything in `journalctl`, except that the log ends with:

> Nov 16 14:20:34 localhost kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ...

How can I dig further in the issue or how to resolve it? I waited about 5 minutes at that hibernation attempt before I force-shutdown the PC.

Comment: I edited the question according to https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/in-what-way-my-question-is-actually-too-broad